# how to input arguments to a function like username=password?

Tags: python

I want my code be like this and use both username and password arguments
in code as string.

```
def check_registration_rules(username='password'):
```

calling function like this:

```
check_registration_rules(parsap1378='pass')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpler, clearer (better, IMHO) solution would be to have 2 function parameters, 1 for the username and 1 for the password.

```
def check_registration_rules(username, password):
    print(type(username), username)  # <class 'str'> parsap1378
    print(type(password), password)  # <class 'str'> pass

check_registration_rules("parsap1378", "pass")
```

But if you really want to pass it like `parsap1378='pass'`, you can use [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
def check_registration_rules(**kwargs):
    username, password = kwargs.popitem()
    print(type(username), username)  # <class 'str'> parsap1378
    print(type(password), password)  # <class 'str'> pass

check_registration_rules(parsap1378='pass')
```

If you are passing other arguments to your function, if they are not of the form `key=val`, you need to pass it **BEFORE** the keyword arguments, as explained in the [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) docs:

```
def check_registration_rules(aaa, bbb, **kwargs):
    print(aaa, bbb)  # 111 222

    username, password = kwargs.popitem()
    print(type(username), username)  # <class 'str'> parsap1378
    print(type(password), password)  # <class 'str'> pass

check_registration_rules(111, 222, parsap1378='pass')
```

If you are passing multiple `username=password` pairs, you need to loop through the `kwargs` like a regular `dict`:

```
def check_registration_rules(**kwargs):
    for username, password in kwargs.items():
        print(type(username), username)
        print(type(password), password)

check_registration_rules(parsap1378='pass', aaa="123", bbb="456")
# <class 'str'> parsap1378
# <class 'str'> pass
# <class 'str'> aaa
# <class 'str'> 123
# <class 'str'> bbb
# <class 'str'> 45
```

Comment: The second solution using `kwargs` is actually really nice because first it matches the OP's structure, second if needed or not it allows to pass multiple username-pass couples and validate all at once...